# How to extend an EMF-based model with listeners for use in a GEF editor?

Tags: eclipse, model-view-controller, listener, eclipse-emf, eclipse-gef

I am creating an Eclipse RCP with a *GEF* editor and an *EMF*-based model.

One thing that is mentioned about the model in the [GEF Book](http://www.qualityeclipse.com/eclipse-gef) is

> The model should broadcast all state changes via **listeners** so that the
>   view can be updated without the model having any direct knowledge of
>   the controller or view.

In the book's example, each model element class, e.g., `Person`, `Marriage`, etc. (the example is a genealogy editor), has methods to add and remove the respective listener, e.g., for `Person` the are:

```java
public void addPersonListener(PersonListener l) {
    listeners.add(l);
}

public void removePersonListener(PersonListener l) {
    listeners.remove(l);
}
```

Unfortunately, the model I use **doesn't have these `add/removeListener` methods**. Now I need a way to extend the model and implement the methods. I have no idea where to start really, as I don't know much about EMF.

The model is graph-based, so it has nodes and edges ("relations"). Elements are added to the graph via calling, e.g., `MyNode node = ExampleFactory.eINSTANCE.createMyNode()` and adding the new node to the graph, e.g., `graph.addMyNode(node)`.

What I don't understand due to my lack of knowldege concerning EMF is where the "extension point" in the model would be.

The model structure is approximately as follows:

`org.example.structure.MyGraph`:

```java
public interface MyGraph {
...
    MyRelation addMyNode(MyNode sourceMyNode, MyNode targetMyNode, 
        MYTYPE_NAME myRelationType);
...
}
```

Then there is als a class `MyGraphImpl`

`org.example.structure.impl.MyGraphImpl`:

```java
public class MyGraphImpl extends Graph implements MyGraph {
...
protected MyGraphImpl() {
    super();
    this.init();
}
...
private void init()
{
    //creates indexes
}
...
@Override
public void addMyNode(MyNode myNode) 
{
    super.addNode(myNode);
}
...
}
```

Do I have to - to put it like that for want of knowledge - **extend the single model classes with EMF** (as described, e.g., on [Lars Vogel's website](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseEMF/ar01s09.html)), or can I extend the model "per hand"?

And: Do I have to extend the `**interface**`s of the model (e.g., `MyGraph`), or their implementation **classes** (e.g., `MyGraphImpl`)?

I'll be very thankful for any pointers in the right direction...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EMF has its own Notification mechanism, there is no need to add another listener-mechanism, a quick google-search gave me another [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseEMFNotification/article.html) of Lars with a nice example that demonstrates this mechanism

Comment: Thanks! I have of course googled a bit before asking here, but it seems I didn't know what to look for due to lack of knowledge about EMF. I'll have a good look at the tut and will see if this gets me anywhere...

Comment: Hm, am I right in assuming that if the model itself doesn't include any `Observer`s, I can create them myself without having to change the model itself? I'm not sure if I understood the tutorial correctly... Thanks (also for the patience with a newb)!

Comment: Okay, I've found another tutorial at eclipse.org (http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-GEF-EMF/gef-emf.html), which deals with bringing GEF and EMF together. I'll check this out in detail.

Comment: Yeah, looks good. You'll find there also the section "Listening to your EMF model" with a snippet regarding the notifiers,

Answer (score 0):

There is **little to no** reasons in using EMF and GEF together. If you model in EMF and using GEF as an editing framework you should consider using GMF http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/gmp/ insted. GMF provides an extension on Draw2D, GEF and EMF, which glues it together seamlessly. And if you're just building nodes and edges considef using Graphity as a much easier framework then GEF of EMF, which will give you quick and nice results very soon.

Comment: Thanks. I have had a look at Graphiti and Spray recently, and will definitely try them out.